# Add markers on bing map polyline in angular using X-map-polyline

Tags: angular, bing-maps, polyline, polylineoptions

Currently i am using X-map to display Bing map and markers using rest API. Now i want to draw route on the map, for that i am using x-map-poly line with sample lat long values. Line is printed on the map but how to add markers for the route? Please advise. Below is my code.

```
<div style="height: 500px;"> 
<x-map #xmap (MapPromise)="mapReady($event)" [Options]="mapOptions"> 
<x-map-marker *ngFor="let marker of markers; let i=index" [Latitude]="marker.porLatitude" [Longitude]="marker.porLongitude" [Title]="marker.billOfLadingNumber" (MarkerClick)="getTandT(marker.billOfLadingNumber,i)"> </x-map-marker> <x-map-polyline *ngIf="isRouteTrue" [Path]="path" [StrokeColor]="blue"
></x-map-polyline> </x-map> </div>
```

---

```
this.path = [ {latitude: 0.1420, longitude: 38.4008 }, 
              {latitude: -6.0865, longitude: 35.9647 }, 
              {latitude: -13.3257, longitude: 36.9873 },   
{latitude: 20.1426, longitude: 38.1303 }, 
{latitude: -28.0750, longitude: 39.4377 },
 {latitude: -35.3627, longitude: 40.5658},
 {latitude: -41.7488, longitude: 41.5070 }, 
{latitude: -49.7708, longitude: 42.6638 },
 {latitude: -55.7413, longitude: 43.6010 }, 
{latitude: -62.4150, longitude: 44.4168 }, 
{latitude: -64.8713, longitude: 42.8862 }, 
{latitude: -73.5347, longitude: 40.4565 } ];
```

---

[bing map markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRsaT.jpg)

Comment: <x-map #xmap (MapPromise)="mapReady($event)" [Options]="mapOptions">
        <x-map-marker *ngFor="let marker of markers; let i=index" [Latitude]="marker.porLatitude"
            [Longitude]="marker.porLongitude" [Title]="marker.billOfLadingNumber"  (MarkerClick)="getTandT(marker.billOfLadingNumber,i)">
        </x-map-marker>
        <x-map-polyline *ngIf="isRouteTrue" [Path]="path" [StrokeColor]="blue" ></x-map-polyline>
    </x-map>